# Vscode auto format code stops working after few runs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am using **vscode-insider** for my c++ CMAKE based project in combination with **C/C++** extention which provides IntelliSense and also clang-format support. So if you press `ctrl+shift+i` or enter `format document` command, it should automatically format your document using `clang-format`. The problem is after executing this command for few times, it will suddenly stop working and won't respond anymore either using the shortcut or the actual command.

At the moment, to make it work again I have to close and run vscode again.

Any ideas about how to find out the issue, is there any log output from vscode?

Comment: Have you ever tried to run clang-format manually? And, what OS are you use?

Comment: Yes, as I said initially it works properly, it has nothing to do with clang-format itself,
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could find the actual problem and also the solution in this github issue from `vscode-cpptools` extension repo:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3285#issuecomment-504519740

It only happens when you have registered multiple projects into your workspace which apparently causes `cpptools` to register multiple duplicate formatters. It means if you use `format document with` option you will have a list of clang formatters which actually one of them will work. AS indicated in the link above, the easiest solution is to simply disable `cpptools`formatter and install `clang-format` extention instead. Please read the issue itself for more details.